# Terraform errors openstack_compute_floatingip_v2: Resource not found

Tags: terraform

When I run terraform I get,

```
openstack_compute_floatingip_v2.sandbox: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Error creating openstack_compute_floatingip_v2: Resource not found
│ 
│   with openstack_compute_floatingip_v2.sandbox,
│   on main.tf line 31, in resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_v2" "sandbox":
│   31: resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_v2" "sandbox" {
```

But it does seem that there is a [`openstack_compute_floatingip_v2` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs/resources/compute_floatingip_v2). This seems to be the line triggering the error,

```
resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_v2" "sandbox" {
        pool = "public"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do to resolve this was migrate to using [`openstack_networking_floatingip_v2`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs/resources/networking_floatingip_v2) instead of the deprecated `openstack_compute_floatingip_v2`. This requires an explicit association with `openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2`.

```
resource "openstack_networking_floatingip_v2" "myip" {
        pool = "pool_name"
}

resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" "bridge" {
        floating_ip = "${openstack_networking_floatingip_v2.myip.address}"
        instance_id = "${openstack_compute_instance_v2.test-server.id}"
}
```